# html : Draw a separated line to three

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, line, draw

Hi I want to draw in my html page a line that spllited to 3 lines.
like in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linear-gradient`:

```css
.hr {
  width:100%;
  height:4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
                    lightseagreen 0, lightseagreen calc(33.3% - 4px),
                    transparent calc(33.3% - 4px), transparent calc(33.3% + 4px),
                    lightseagreen calc(33.3% + 4px), lightseagreen calc(66.6% - 4px),
                    transparent calc(66.6% - 4px),  transparent calc(66.6% + 4px),
                    lightgray calc(66.6% + 4px), lightgray 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"></div>
```

or a flex layout:

```css
.hr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hr>span {
  width: 32.6%;
  background-color: lightgray; 
}

.hr>span.filled {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
  <span class="filled"></span>
  <span class="filled"></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```